# How to set an attribute in a model property

Tags: django, django-models

I want to add a label attribute to a model property, so I can access a verbose name for it:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    @property
    def is_closed(self):
        setattr(self.is_closed, 'label', 'is the object closed?')
        if self.list_closure_datetime:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

However, `obj.is_closed.label` returns

> maximum recursion depth exceeded

Where am I going wrong? How do I fix this so I can define a verbose name inside the property and call it like `obj.is_closed.label`?

Comment: That is because you call `self.is_closed` in `self.is_closed.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks how do I fix this? – titan2891 9 mins ago   Delete

Comment: you can not set attributes to a property, so I'm afraid you can not set a label here.